# Filenet libraries for C# desktop applications

Tags: c#, vb6, filenet-p8, filenet

I have a VB6 application which uses `FnNFO.tlb` - Filenet Panagon IDM Objects 3.2 and `fnerrlks.tlb` - Filenet Panagon IDM Error Objects 3.2 to login to filenet library and do basic operations.

Now I want to rewrite the application in C#. As per my search I got a link about [Content Engine Java and .NET APIs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.0.0/com.ibm.p8.common.dev.doc/upg_custom_apps/content_java_net_apis.htm)  but I am not sure whether it is replacement for `FnNFO.tlb` and `fnnerrlks.tlb`. So which library should I use as a replacement for above type libraries?

Comment: The link you found is related to IBM Filenet P8 Content Engine which is an evolution of Filenet Panagon product series, and it works in a different manner. Please add more details about what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're overthinking it.  Add the reference to the IDM COM dll's or tlb's to the project and let the IDE handle building the interop references then import the component being used. You won't get the IDE autocomplete but the methods will still work. Where possible use early binding and remember the IDM COM objects are STA so you should attribute methods using them with "STAThread". Remember to pass null or missing types for optional parameters and dispose of the COM objects when you're done.

Comment: ok but you can use the COM dlls, but I would say that those APIs are quite outdated. The problem is that Filenet P8 are quite different from the COM ones or am i mistaken?